# Why failed to load simple app in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have just started development in Spring MVC. Just hating it. Well, This is a very simple app. I follow the tutorial from here. [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc7NIVJEdb4). I do same as he did in the tutorial. But I have an error. This is the output in the console.

```js
Dec 19, 2018 1:25:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/springexamples] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.java:3307)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1985)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1911)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:467)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
 at com.letsstartcoding.springexamples.dao.StudentDAO.count(StudentDAO.java:182)
 at com.letsstartcoding.springexamples.controller.StudentEnrollmentController.initializePageCount(StudentEnrollmentController.java:152)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
 at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:142)
 at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:111)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:848)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I search everywhere and try but nothing helps me. Here is the pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.letsstartcoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>springexamples</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springexamples Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
    <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
    <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springexamples</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here is the spring-servlet.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.letsstartcoding.springexamples" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world"></property>  
<property name="username" value="root"></property>  
<property name="password" value="123456"></property>  
</bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dao" class="com.letsstartcoding.springexamples.dao.StudentDAO">  
<property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
</bean>  
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `mysql-connector-java` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)